# React Attempted import error: 'FreeSurferLoader' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, webgl

В React приложении собираюсь использовать Three.js, но мне нужно нужно расширить модуль THREE, при попытке это сделать получаю такую ошибку **"Attempted import error: 'FreeSurferLoader' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE')."** Не понимаю эту ошибку я ведь пытаюсь не получить эту функцию а присвоить. На чистом js без реакта всё работает.

Версии: 
React - 17.0.2, 
Three.js - 131

Код:

```
import * as THREE from "three";

THREE.FreeSurferLoader = function () {};

...
```

P.S. эту логику пишу не в компоненте а в отдельном файле.

Comment: FreeSurferLoader не доступен для експотра всё логично
Поробуй что то на подобие THREE.FreeSurferLoader.prototype

Comment: Пробовал ничего не изменилось, всё та же ошибка